# How to subscribe Input property to call out function Angular 2+

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

Hi I have an issue like in subject:
My Parent component passes the value to his child component like this:

```
<em-event-list  [sumListEvents]="sumListEvents"></em-event-list>
```

So when when value *sumListEvents* will change I want to subscribe that value to call out the function from Service. This is how my children component looks:

```
 @Input() sumListEvents: Observable<number>;
 private events: Event[] = [];

 constructor(private dataService: EventListService) { 
    let loadSubscription = this.sumListEvents.subscribe(
      value => {
        this.events = this.dataService.showEvents(value)
      }
    )
  }
```

But I receive error on subscribe `Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined` in the *sumListEvents*. Any ideas?

Comment: Move code to ngOnInit hook

Comment: still error `this.sumListEvents.subscribe is not a function`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sumListEvents` is not available at the moment you need it. You can use `*ngIf` to subscribe only when `sumListEvents` available.

```
<em-event-list *ngIf [sumListEvents]="sumListEvents"></em-event-list>
```

This will work but it might not be a best practise to pass event to the child and subscribe it in a child.

You may refer to https://scotch.io/tutorials/3-ways-to-pass-async-data-to-angular-2-child-components for other ways to pass async data to child component.

Answer (score 0):

A better approach will be to use the `async` pipe and a `setter`.

```
<em-event-list *ngIf [sumList]="sumListEvents$ | async"></em-event-list>

 @Input() set sumList(value) {
   if(value) {
     this.events = this.dataService.showEvents(value);
   }      
 }

 private events: Event[] = [];

 constructor(private dataService: EventListService) { }
```